# Accessibility with Google Slides Embed on a webpage

Tags: accessibility

Got a site with powerpoint presentations that the client wants embedded, the embedding is being done via google docs embed. I have been doing some accessibility testing, albeit not particularly in-depth but even with OS X screen reader it is not having any luck reading the slides. (I am aware slides are probably terrible for accessibility anyway). I can get the text content of the slides stripped out via the Google API, but I don't know if thats the best thing, to include it on the page below/above the iframe embed with one of the CSS tricks for hiding it from normal view?

I am aware of iframe title and aria-label but those seem to imply they are only to describe the contents of the iframe, which I am doing, but I need somewhere that can contain more text.

Has anyone got any good tips for the best way to deal with such things? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Embedding rich 3rd-party content in web pages poses many challenges.

When we put something like this in a web page, we typically think we're adding a bit of "content", but it often amounts to embedding a complex application; and the user interface, semantics, and presentation are outside of our control. In your case it's a presentation slide deck, but it could also be a Flash/Silverlight/Java applet, a slippy map, interactive SVG infographic, a 3D-panorama, virtual tour, zoomable image, chemical molecule viewer, or who-knows-what. (Note: I'm not familiar with the Google docs embed/API specifically, so most parts of my answer will address these rich content cases in general.)

Even if the embedded rich 3rd-party content/application is accessible today, there's no guarantee it will remain so after the 3rd-party system gets an update.

So what can you do? The safest thing might be to assume it's inaccessible, and consider the best way to provide an accessible alternative. The [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) (WCAG) calls this a "conforming alternate version", and it sounds like you're already thinking along these lines.

An important caveat to all of this, is that the use of "conforming alternate versions" isn't considered ideal by many accessibility specialists. **It's greatly preferred to make your main content accessible as you can.**

Some relevant parts of WCAG:

- [Understanding conformance](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/conformance), especially the section about "Understanding Conforming Alternate Versions".
- [Technique G190: Providing a link adjacent to or associated with a non-conforming object that links to a conforming alternate version.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G190)
- [F19: Failure of Conformance Requirement 1 due to not providing a method for the user to find the alternative conforming version of a non-conforming Web page.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F19)
- It's worth mentioning the 3rd-party content in your website's accessibility statement. [Statement of Partial Conformance - Third Party Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#conformance-partial) offers guidance about that.

The crucial thing about conforming alternate versions, is that it's no use at all if the user isn't made aware of it, or isn't able to reach it.

Implementation-wise, there are a variety of approaches you might take. In many ways, providing an alternative for embedded rich content is similar to providing a long description of a complex image, or a transcript of a video. Have a look at these WAI tutorials for some ideas.

- [Web Accessibility Tutorials: Complex Images](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/complex/)
- [Making Audio and Video Media Accessible: Where to Put Transcripts](https://www.w3.org/WAI/media/av/transcripts/#where-to-put-transcripts)

> I can get the text content of the slides stripped out via the Google API

It sounds like you're trying to automate the process. That's fine, but it might not give satisfactory results. Some things you should consider:

- Is the text content alone going to be enough? Presentations often have images too. Did the author provide text alternatives for these images, and are they present in the text extracted via the API? If the author hasn't provided text alternatives for images in the slide deck, the text you get from the API won't be telling the whole story.
- Not all text in slides carries the same weight. Some slides serve to introduce sections, some slides have headings. Does the text obtained from the API convey these relationships?
- Lists are very commonly found in presentation. Does the text obtained from the API preserve this structure?
- Slides sometimes contain links. Are these included in the text obtained from the API, so the links are available to everybody using the alternative version?
- Slides sometimes contain tables and charts. How will the information in these be conveyed in your alterative version? Is the information included in the text obtained from the API?
- Sometimes, presentation decks also contain rich 3rd-party embedded content themselves! A slide containing a video, or an animated GIF are examples of this. If so, you can find yourself with a much more complex challenge.
- ... and many other meaningful info and relationships. Quotations, code samples, etc.

If any of the above points give cause for concern, you will need to consider managing your alternative version manually.

The "conforming alternative version" has to conform to WCAG; if you just offer a choice of two non-conforming version, that doesn't satisfy WCAG.

> include it on the page below/above the iframe embed with one of the CSS tricks for hiding it from normal view?

No, I wouldn't recommend that. I assume you're refering to visually-hidden text, using CSS utility classes such as `.visually-hidden` or `.sr-only`. It sounds like you're only thinking about screen reader users.

You need to offer the alternative version available to *everybody*, not just one group of users who you think will need it.

- Many groups of users may experience difficulty using the rich 3rd-party embedded content. This includes people using the keyboard only, screen readers, magnifiers, speech control, switch access, or other tools. The conforming alternative version can be navigated like a normal web page though.
- The 3rd-party content likely has a different visual style, and it may not be *adaptable* in the same way as the page it is embedded in. That can frustrate people who make use of browser zooming, text resizing, font preferences, reader mode, Windows high-contrast themes, viewport resizing, and other user-applied presentation changes. The conforming alternate version should be as adaptable as the rest of your site.

Rather than hiding the alternative version in a visually-hidden container, here are some other ways to present it. The first two are the simplest and most reliable.

- Put it on the same page, just after the original content, visible to everybody.
- Put it in a collapsible disclosure element just after the embedded content. A `<details>` element is an easy way to achieve this. This is useful if the alternative version is quite long.
- Put it elsewhere on the same page, and tell users where to find it. An internal link can help here.
- Put it on a separate page, with a link next to the embedded content. I'm less keen on this approach. Only use it if you can commit to maintaining both pages.
- Provide a way for users to switch between the two versions. For example some buttons, or a tabbed UI. However, you must also ensure that the switching mechanism is accessible. That might mean a full-blown ARIA tabs implementation.

> I am aware of iframe title and aria-label but those seem to imply they are only to describe the contents of the iframe

Giving the iFrame a useful name is important. It's also a useful mechanism to inform screen reader users that an alternative version is available. The WAI Complex Images tutorial linked above has some similar approaches. Example: `<iframe title="Google Slides Presentation of FOO BAR BAZ. Link to text version follows this frame.">`. This only helps screen reader users though; you still need to make the availability of the alternative version clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

How committed are you to using Google Docs for displaying these slides?

Any accessibility enhancements that you'll be able to implement on Google Slides won't be very good.

One way around this whole thing is to offer PDF versions of the slides that have been fully-remediated for accessibility instead of using Google Slides. That would potentially be a single solution that could be accessible to all visitors. Going this route means that you wouldn't have multiple copies of the same slides to update, which could lead to a split in content if one gets updated and the other is forgotten.

If you're really set on having the slides embedded in the page, then you could offer both formats by applying `aria-hidden` to the embedded `iframe` and then hiding the PDF links from sighted users using CSS clip, or by positioning content off-screen.

Comment: What's your intention behind putting `aria-hidden` on the iFrame? That doesn't "offer both formats"; on the contrary, it will prevent some users from even knowing it's there at all.  Meanwhile, visually hidden links are poor idea for two reasons. Firstly, they will be a failure of WCAG success criterion 2.4.7 "Focus Visible". Secondly, why shouldn't sighted users know that a PDF is available? Particularly after you've gone to the effort of making the PDFs accessible.

Comment: @andrewmacpherson - It sounds like your goal here is not to seek clarification on a question, but rather to discredit other answers and offer a justification for why you think your answer is better.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory, because first you say that the PDFs would be accessible to all visitors, then you suggest that the links be hidden from sighted users.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding my answer. I advocated for PDF instead of Google Slides. I then said, if the OP is insistent on having Google Slides, they could offer those slides to sighted visitors only, and offer an accessible PDF to users of assistive technology. I offered a technical mechanism for making that happen where each audience won't see the other version.

Comment: That's precisely my point. There's no good reason to restrict the PDFs to assistive tech users, regardless of whether the iframe is hidden. It's putting users into silos, instead of letting them choose which version they want to try using. As a sighted user, I'd love to know about the PDF links so I can print them. As a keyboard user, visually hidden links are a great nuisance.

Comment: and by hiding the iframe from assistive tech users, you deny them the opportunity to even try to use it, let alone benefiting from any future improvements that the 3rd-party embedded content provider makes (Google aren't always going to be innaccessible).